# Binary converter tool/script in OS X (to generate webfont from old PostScript font file)?

Tags: macos, terminal, webfonts, mac-classic

I have been told I need to use [Mac Binary Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macbinconv/) to convert a postscript font into a macbinary .bin file for use with [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/blog/2010/12/how-to-use-the-generator).

I am generally quite comfortable with command line (using Ruby gems & ssh mainly) but how do I add this tool to my command line and use it? Does it need to sit in my path somewhere first?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

sourceforge Mac Binary Converter is not working. Download code from  [sourceforge](http://macbinconv.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/macbinconv/)

Open terminal and compile

```
$ cd /macbinconv/Make/PB
$ xcodebuild -configuration Release
```

Or download Mac Binary Converter from this [shared link](https://www.idrive.com/idrive/sh/sh?k=y7v8k1j7i1)

Comment: Thank you but there is no documentation so I am not sure how to use the tool once I have compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The above linked to `macbinconv` code does not compile on recent OS X versions (I've tested with 10.9).

There are at least two other options:

- Use **Stuffit Deluxe** to create the macbinary (.bin) or binhex (.hqx) files from you old resource-fork style Postscript Mac fonts, as required for FontSquirrel webfont generator.*
- There's a tool in the App Store called **[OldHex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oldhex/id415628440?mt=12)** that generates binhex (.hqx) files, including the ressource fork.

Both approaches worked for me, and I was able to upload the resulting files to FontSquirrel. But there, I got the following message:

> The font is corrupt and cannot be converted

In the end, though, I succeeded along the following, alternative route:

1. Use the command line tool **[Fondu](http://fondu.sourceforge.net/)** to convert the file from StuffIt Deluxe to a Printer Font Binary (.pfb).
   `fondu` already is available in Terminal.app if you have **[MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/)** installed.
2. Next, with the **[fontconverter.org](http://www.fontconverter.org/)** online tool, generate an OpenType font file (.otf) from said printer font binary – because with OTF, you have more options.
3. Convert your OpenType files with **[Fontie](https://fontie.flowyapps.com/)** or **[Web Font Generator](https://www.web-font-generator.com/)**.

**Bada Bing!** – with either online tool, I got webfonts that worked across all browsers and platforms. (Still no dice with FontSquirrel, but your milage may vary.)

Watch out for special characters that might not have been available at the time your old font files were created – with my 1992 sample, the `@` character was missing. ;-)

**  You may demo Stuffit Deluxe at no cost with the fully functional, **[limitation-free trial version](http://my.smithmicro.com/stuffit-deluxe-mac-trial.html)**, but a credit card and a later cancellation of subscription is required.) — You wil find the neccessary commands in the toolbar menu, and not in the apps it places in your Applications folder.*

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of macOS include a suite of utilities which can be used to perform these conversions: `applesingle`, `binhex`, and `macbinary`. Of these, you'll want `macbinary` to create `.bin` files.

Frustratingly, `macbinary` defaults to the rarely used Type 3 encoding. You will need to pass `-t 2` to get output in a format that vintage tools will expect, e.g.

```
macbinary encode -t 2 -o Example.bin Example
```